# Do @Service JBoss EJB's support transactions?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb, ejb-3.0, jta

Does anyone know if JBoss @Service EJB's support transactions?  I'd like to work with an EntityManager but am getting "EntityManager must be used within a transaction" errors.  Explicitly specifying container-managed transactions and REQUIRED transactions on the EJB doesn't make a difference.

Thanks.

**Update**

Here is the code I am using to get an EntityManager:

```
   @PersistenceContext(unitName = "MyPersistenceContextName")
   private EntityManager m_entityManager;
```

And here is the code that failed:

```
  m_entityManager.persist( objectToSave);
  m_entityManager.flush();
```

It failed on the first line.

Comment: In theory @Service annotation supports local and remote interfaces managed by the container, so it would have transactional support. Please post your code.

Comment: Just to be sure, we talk about `org.jboss.annotation.ejb.Service`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By applying annotation `@Service`, it will install the bean in the `MBean` server with specific name, which runs on a different classloader & your application on another one. Therefore, this may be the reason why MBean not support transaction & not be able to access the context.

Instead of interacting with database through MBean, you can delegate it to other EJB bean, which can be accessed through JNDI lookup.